# What is the common approach to offering an ad version of your app when users do not have an account?

Tags: android, admob, react-native

I will be placing google ads in my mobile app but because it's more or less just an app which provides data, I will not be implementing any sort of user registration.

I would like to know what is the correct protocol for submitting a paid and unpaid version **of the same app** one is just without ads. Is it as simple as create 2 apps in the google app console and export one with ads built in and one without, or is there some form of API that you can use?

If it is just creating 2 app projects in the console, do I have to change the package name? Are there any conflicts that I should look for? I am using React-Native if that is important and for now exporting to only Android.

---

Edit:
People have recommended I use a single in-app purchase, but my issue is how am I supposed to detect whether a user has paid for the app or not if I'm not tracking users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paid and Free versions of android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999062/paid-and-free-versions-of-android-app)

Comment: most efficient way is to develop single app and implement in-app purchases where users have option to pay to remove ads

Comment: Is it possible to do that without the user needing an account though?